# How to access UWP APIs from Qt Application?

Tags: c++, qt, uwp, qt-creator

I am creating an application to run on Windows 10 using Qt Creator.

Is it possible to access the [rich APIs available to UWP applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-and-com-for-uwp-apps) from my the C++ Qt project?

I have seen [this tutorial](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#ahs7RDilZ5wwVG1d.97) but it is just specific for Visual Studio, so did not help me much.

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "rich APIs." UWP is a limited subset of Win32 so there's nothing about it I'd call "rich." That said UWP is supported by Qt.

Answer (score 1):

Qt code is C++ code. That you're using Qt doesn't mean all that much. You'll need to use some projection of Windows Runtime to C++. The canonical one is [C++/WinRT](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt). You can then easily use the runtime APIs from your code.

See [this blog post](https://moderncpp.com/2017/11/15/cppwinrt-exe-in-the-windows-sdk/) for a quick introduction.